# Price history based on date

Tags: sql-server

Have a requirement to list all price change as a single output.

My table has data as below

Let's call the table PRICE_HIST

```
Itemid  Price   Price_Change_Date
111A112 1,000.00    10/03/2014
111A114 1,111.00    10/03/2014
111A11  1,111.00    10/03/2014
111A111 1,000.00    10/03/2014
111A114 2,222.00    10/09/2014
111A111 2,222.00    10/09/2014
```

Need help with Query to get output as below.

```
Itemid  Last_Modified   Current_Price Last_Change Last_Change1 Last_Change2
111A112 10/03/2014      1,000.00      NA          NA           NA
111A11  10/03/2014      1,111.00      NA          NA           NA
111A114 10/09/2014      2,222.00      1,111.00    NA           NA
111A111 10/09/2014      2,222.00      1,000.00    NA           NA
```

First time user :-( Unable to format the code

Comment: can you show us your query?

Comment: So what all have you tried so far?  Do you have an example query that you are getting errors with?

Comment: Hmm Tried with Top 1 and then TOp2 eliminating one.. Didn't worked Next tried to get a sub Query with Rank Function but it too Not worked.

Comment: you're going to have to pivot the data somehow.

Comment: Store money as decimal, and store dates as dates

Comment: some this i tried.. I know its a mess :-)

Comment: select a.item_code,a.Date_Modified as Last_Modified_Date,( 
SELECT  TOP (1)Item_Price 
from PRICE_HIST 
where Item_Code=a.item_code 
ORDER  BY Date_Modified DESC) as Current_price,( 
SELECT  TOP (2)Item_Price 
from PRICE_HIST 
where Item_Code=a.item_code 
 and Item_Price<>current_price

Comment: SELECT  TOP(1)Item_Price from PRICE_HIST 
where Item_Code=a.item_code ORDER BY Date_Modified DESC)  ORDER BY Date_Modified DESC) as Last_Changed_Price from PRICE_HIST a where a.Item_Price= (SELECT TOP (1)Item_Price from PRICE_HIST where Item_Code=5 
ORDER BY Date_Modified DESC)
and b.Item_Price= (SELECT TOP (2)Item_Price 
from PRICE_HIST where Item_Code=5e and item_price<> a.item_price 
ORDER  BY Date_Modified DESC) and c.Item_Price= (SELECT TOP (3)Item_Price from PRICE_HIST where Item_Code=a.item_code and item_price<> a.item_price and b.item_price<> a.item_price  
ORDER BY Date_Modified DESC)

Comment: SELECT T0.Item_Code,MAX(T0.Date_modified) 'Latest', (
SELECT MAX(Item_Price),T1.Date_modified) 'Previous' 
FROM PRICE_HIST 
WHERE Item_Code=T0.Item_Code 
 AND Date_modified= MAX(T0.Date_modified)) 'Last Price'
FROM PRICE_HIST   T0 
where 
Group By T0.Item_Code

Comment: update your question and format the queries... that's very hard to read

Comment: Now I'm nearly as confused as you. Which RDBMS?

Comment: Sql Server 2008 and  Teradata

Comment: @Machha why would you tag this with MySQL if you're using sql server......

Comment: My Bad, Changed the Tag.. And Thanks Sql Server version worked!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is tagged with MySQL.

This is a **MySQL solution:**

```
select itemid,
       max(price_date) as last_modified,
       max(case when rn = 1 then price end) as current_price,
       max(case when rn = 2 then price end) as last_change,
       max(case when rn = 3 then price end) as last_change1,
       max(case when rn = 4 then price end) as last_change2
from
(
select @rn := case
         when @itemid = itemid then
          @rn + 1
         else
          1
       end as rn,
       @itemid    := itemid    as itemid,
       price,
       price_date
  from price_hist
 cross join (select @rn := 0, @itemid := '') as t
 order by itemid, price_date desc
) x
group by itemid
order by last_modified, itemid
```

This uses variables to mimic the row_number() functionality that is available in other databases, essentially partitioning on itemid. It then uses conditional aggregation to pivot the 4 latest prices for each item.

If you're actually using SQL Server, you can use row_number()

This is a **SQL Server solution:**

```
select itemid,
       max(price_date) as last_modified,
       max(case when rn = 1 then price end) as current_price,
       max(case when rn = 2 then price end) as last_change,
       max(case when rn = 3 then price end) as last_change1,
       max(case when rn = 4 then price end) as last_change2
from
(
select row_number() over (partition by itemid order by itemid, price_date desc) as rn,
       itemid,
       price,
       price_date
  from price_hist
) x
group by itemid
order by last_modified, itemid
```